# Disable logger from imported module in a custom module

Tags: python, logging

I usually define my logger in **main.py** and then I use the same format in all my other custom modules and classes.

However, since I imported the **discovery** module within **MyClass** I get lots of logs that I don't want. How can I disable only the discovery logs while keeping all others?

I've tried

**main.py**

```
import logging 
import MyClass

logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO, format = '%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(module)s:%(message)s') 
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

myc = MyClass.MyClass()
myc.do_something()
```

**MyClass.py**

```
import logging
from googleapiclient import discovery

class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def do_something(self):
    # code using discovery
```

I've tried adding this to **MyClass** after importing both logging and discovery but it didn't help:

```
logging.getLogger('discovery').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

These are the logs I'm trying to get rid of:

> 2018-08-10 16:11:11,702:INFO:discovery:URL being requested: GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest 2018-08-10
>   16:11:11,800:INFO:discovery:URL being requested: GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/teamdrives?alt=json

Comment: Wrong logger - `discovery` is not `googleapiclient.discovery`.

Comment: Duh! Thanks, I added that and it worked.